# angular post request with content-type application/json not working

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, angular8, angular-httpclient, angular-http

I try to send post request with angular but when i set content-type to application/json 
the request content-type always not set and the HTTP method always removed and all posted data removed from request body 
here my code

[image]

and here my request

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> the HTTP method always removed and all posted data removed from request body

In the screenshot you shared, we can find that the request you captured is a `OPTIONS` request ([preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request)), not actual `POST` request. So the data you posted is not in request body.

Besides, the following code snippet works well on my side, you can refer to it.

```
var student = {'name' : 'testuser', 'age' : 29};

const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type','application/json');

this.http.post<Student>('https://xxxx/student',JSON.stringify(student),{headers:headers})
.subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Controller and Action

```
[Route("[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class StudentController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Post(Student student)
    {
        return Ok(student);
    }
}
```

Test Result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to expand Fei Han answer. If you are using `asp core` as server side you should configure Cors in Startup.cs like this :

```
app.UseCors(x =>
    x.AllowAnyHeader()
    .AllowAnyMethod()
    .AllowAnyOrigin());
```

Answer (score -1):

If you set Accept headers like this, its enough.

```
 const headers = new HttpHeaders()
      .set('Accept', 'application/json');
```

No need to set content headers.

Comment: in this case the data posted to server but the content-type will be text plain and this request will give me exception unsupored mediatype